# Copy ellision и 17 стандарт

Tags: c++, c++17, clang++

Возникло несколько вопросав в связи с copy ellision, c++17 и использованием компилятора clang++-8.

1) copy ellision при передаче временного объекта в функцию - это введено 17 стандартом?

2) компилятор (clang++-8) выдает предупреждение в данном случае:

```
my_fun(std::move(std::string("string")));
```

о том, что сдесь работает copy ellision (тобишь move не нужен). Но, в случае, если работаю с типам QPixmap (qt512) в точно такой же ситуации предупреждение не выдается. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Наверное потому, что  QPixmap не простой тип данных

Comment: @ARHovsepyan что вы имеете ввиду под "простым" типом данных? Как это может влиять на copy ellision?

Comment: птд я понимаю точно так же, как определено в стандарте, а как может повлиять, не смогу рассказать. Я лишь предпологаю.

Comment: [mcve] с опция компилятора в студию... и что именно за warning? у меня он пока не воспроизводится...

Comment: @Fat-Zer ошибочка вышла: компилятор не g++-8, а clang++-8. g++ такой опции не имеет.

Comment: copy elision при передаче объекта в функцию нет, зато в этом примере `std::move` является бессмысленным, так как `std::string("string")` уже rvalue

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, VTT уже сказал, в чём суть... диагностика компилятора, пожалуй, не совсем корректна, должно быть что-то вроде «moving a temporary object leads to excessive copying» и это верно для всех версий C++ (в которых есть `std::move`)... А то что на `QPixmap` (как и на все классы без конструктора перемещения) не выдаётся предупреждение — я бы сказал, что это баг clang'а; в этом случае оно как раз пригодилось бы больше...

Comment: @Fat-Zer спасибо. А по поводу фразы "как и на все классы без конструктора перемещения" - это предположение, проверяли или из документации?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, [проверял](https://paste.pound-python.org/show/PQfZBa3uAuFLC4r84BhF/).